Why is my transaction log full of LOP_LOCK_XACT?
I have recently experienced a strange issue with one of our sql server staging databases, whereby the transaction log and log backups suddenly grew around a hundredfold in size, causing a disk space issue within the space of a couple of hours.
The server is SQL2019 and the database uses FULL logging mode. We take a full backup daily and log backups hourly. Ordinarily the log backups are around 250MB in size, but at the time of the issue they jumped to around 25GB, and the transaction log grew from around 15GB to over 200GB at which point the disk filled up.
Searching through SQL server logs and the application logs from the java application that is interacting with the database did not show any obvious answer so I resorted to using the MS fn_dump_dblog function to try and look at the transaction log backups
What I found was that 99.9% of the whole log backup was LOP_LOCK_XACT operations, over 2 billion such operations in one hours worth of log backup. Most of the columns retrieved for these operations are NULL, there is no allocation unit value with which to link it to a table.
Every such row appears to pertain to the same transaction and the LSN's are all concurrent. The Lock information appears as 'HoBt 0:ACQUIRE_LOCK_IX ROWGROUP: 0:72057594066239488:7'
Looking at 'healthy' log backups in comparison there are still a lot of LOP_LOCK_XACT entries but they are matched with other corresponding operations such as LOP_BEGIN and LOP_COMMIT
I'm a bit stuck on figuring out what could cause such behaviour, it's as if lock requests are being spammed by the connecting applications but without an allocation id I am unsure as to figure out what the lock request is for or why
Any help would be appreciated.

The transaction log is full because something is running SQL that modifies a lot of rows. The transaction log isn't a file log, it contains the "before" and "after" row data so the rows can be restored if something goes wrong. We can't guess what's using the database or what it's doing to it. If staging involves deleting and refilling tables you'll see a lot of transaction log records.

You can't view the contents of the transaction log directly which means you did something to inspect specific transactions. What were those? to the same transaction what's that transaction doing?

If some script is DELETEing a table before refilling it, you should replace DELETE with TRUNCATE TABLE or use partition switching to switch out the entire table to some "xyz_old" table that can be truncated separately. Partition switching is a metadata operation and completes almost instantly

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm using fn_dump_dblog to view transaction log backups, it is an undocumented MS function that allows viewing transaction logs or log backups. I'm aware of how transactions work, what I'm not certain of is why one particular transaction is creating millions upon millions of concurrent lock requests
Also, there are no deletes, only inserts and updates. Deleting data only happens in  a seprate purge process at specified intervals.

So what does that transaction do? You already mentioned what you used but not what you saw. What does that transaction do? Millions of records will be generated if the code modifies millions of rows. Triggers that modify other tables will result in more log records. An UPDATE results in multiple records, storing both the old and new data. purge process at specified intervals. that will generate log records too

If you google for the message names you'll find Remu Rusanu's How to read and interpret the SQL Server log. This explains what the messages mean how to use fn_dblog and other techniques to find the actual statements that cause problems. The messages you mentioned appear near the rows Remu Rusanu uses to find the actual statements, like LOP_INSERT_ROWS and LOP_MODIFY_ROWS. What other rows are there in the transaction's log records? We can't query your database to find them
